# How to show the tooltip beside the Icon

Tags: html, css, tooltip

I have 4-5 input fields on my form and each label has an I icon where the user can hover to get some more information.

I tried the below code. I have some issues with CSS. I have to show the tooltip box near the I icon and I can't assign `right` and `top` values to each toolbox because there are more chances to increase the label length.

```css
.toolinformation i {
  color: #ccc;
}

.toolbox {
  display: inline-block;
  /*width: 200px;*/
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
}

.tooltip-left::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 0px;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  border: 15px solid transparent;
  border-left: 0;
  border-right: 15px solid #fefcdc;
  transform: translate(calc(-100% - 0px), -50%);
}

.toolbox p {
  font-size: 12px;
  background-color: #fefcdc;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  text-align: left;
}

.topTooltip,
.loadingTooltip {
  right: -150px;
  top: -26px
}

.loadingTooltip {
  right: 0;
}

.areaTooltip {
  right: -88px;
  top: -8px;
}

.toolinformation:hover~.toolbox {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container mt-5 pt-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xxl-4 col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <div class="form-group position-relative">
        <label for="" class="form-label">abcdref
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="toolinformation"><i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i></a> 
        <div class="topTooltip toolbox tooltip-left"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit<br /> amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,<br /> sed do eiusmod</p></div>
          </label>
        <input type="text" name="" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xxl-4 col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <div class="form-group position-relative">
        <label for="" class="form-label">asdfhgj asdfd abcdref abcdref
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="toolinformation"><i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i></a> 
            <div class="areaTooltip toolbox tooltip-left"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit<br /> amet, consectetur<br /> adipisicing</p></div>
               </label>
        <input type="text" name="" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xxl-4 col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <div class="form-group mb-4 position-relative">
        <label for="" class="form-label">trewqwertyui gtfrdesewa asd gtfrdesewa asd
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="toolinformation"><i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i></a> 
             <div class="areaTooltip toolbox tooltip-left"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit<br /> amet, consectetur<br /> adipisicing</p></div>
         </label>
        <input type="text" name="" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xxl-4 col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <div class="form-group customrange position-relative">
        <label>mkjnhbgf
           <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="toolinformation"><i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i></a> 
         <div class="loadingTooltip toolbox tooltip-left"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit<br /> amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,<br /> sed do eiusmod empor <br />incididunt ut labore</p></div>
            </label>
        <input type="text" name="" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/97446b8f60.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Why do you have a different tooltip class for each element?

Comment: @dalelandry, we can make it one in class. I was testing this.

Answer (score -1):

change

```
 .toolinformation:hover ~ .toolbox {
             display: block; 
             
        }
```

to use inline-block so it can inherit from the parent

```
 .toolinformation:hover ~ .toolbox {
 
            display: inline-block;
        }
```

remove any negative right offest by change

```
.topTooltip,
.loadingTooltip {
  right: -150px;
  top: -26px
}
```

to be

```
.topTooltip,
.loadingTooltip {

  top: -26px
}
```

```css
.toolinformation i {
    color: #ccc;
    }

    .toolbox {
  
    /*width: 200px;*/
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    }

    .tooltip-left::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 0px;
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
    border: 15px solid transparent;
    border-left: 0;
    border-right: 15px solid #fefcdc;
    transform: translate(calc(-100% - 0px), -50%);
    }

    .toolbox p {
    font-size: 12px;
    background-color: #fefcdc;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    text-align: left;
    }

    .topTooltip,
    .loadingTooltip {
 
    top: -26px
    }

    .loadingTooltip {
 
    }

        .areaTooltip {
            top: -26px;
        }

        .toolinformation:hover ~ .toolbox {
            /*  display: block; 
             use inline-block to inherit from parent and remove any left with negative */

            display: inline-block;
        }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container mt-5 pt-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xxl-4 col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <div class="form-group position-relative">
        <label for="" class="form-label">abcdref
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="toolinformation"><i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i></a> 
        <div class="topTooltip toolbox tooltip-left"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit<br /> amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,<br /> sed do eiusmod</p></div>
          </label>
        <input type="text" name="" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xxl-4 col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <div class="form-group position-relative">
        <label for="" class="form-label">asdfhgj asdfd abcdref abcdref
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="toolinformation"><i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i></a> 
            <div class="areaTooltip toolbox tooltip-left"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit<br /> amet, consectetur<br /> adipisicing</p></div>
               </label>
        <input type="text" name="" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xxl-4 col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <div class="form-group mb-4 position-relative">
        <label for="" class="form-label">trewqwertyui gtfrdesewa asd gtfrdesewa asd
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="toolinformation"><i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i></a> 
             <div class="areaTooltip toolbox tooltip-left"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit<br /> amet, consectetur<br /> adipisicing</p></div>
         </label>
        <input type="text" name="" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xxl-4 col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <div class="form-group customrange position-relative">
        <label>mkjnhbgf
           <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="toolinformation"><i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i></a> 
         <div class="loadingTooltip toolbox tooltip-left"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit<br /> amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,<br /> sed do eiusmod empor <br />incididunt ut labore</p></div>
            </label>
        <input type="text" name="" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/97446b8f60.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: I checked your snippet, tooltip not displaying, and can you explain to me what is the issue with my code.

Comment: is your snippet working? i checked but it's not showing the tooltip